# faq bootstrap sample --> not working has script error on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have below html. It consists of bootstrap and css url file. And It has two accordion item tab. But find that it has javascript error when open. And when I click on the accordion, it does not show answer. Is there any wrong??

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Default collapse with scaling icon</h3>
        <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion0">
        FAQ Sample Test
                <div class="panel panel-default ">
                    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion0" data-target="#0">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"> 
                            <a href="#" class="ing">
                                Testing Question 1 Title
                            </a>
                          </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="0" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h5><span class="label label-primary">Answer</span></h5>
                            Testing Question 1 Content
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default ">
                    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion0" data-target="#1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"> 
                            <a href="#" class="ing">
                                Testing Question 2 Title
                            </a>
                          </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h5><span class="label label-primary">Answer</span></h5>
                            Testing Question 2 Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you need to include jQuery also.

```
<script 
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Make sure you included jQuery before including bootstrap.js script

```html
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
       <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Included jQuery right before bootstrap.js -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Default collapse with scaling icon</h3>
            <div class="panel-group" id="faqAccordion0">
            FAQ Sample Test
                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion0" data-target="#0">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"> 
                                <a href="#" class="ing">
                                    Testing Question 1 Title
                                </a>
                              </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="0" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <h5><span class="label label-primary">Answer</span></h5>
                                Testing Question 1 Content
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faqAccordion0" data-target="#1">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"> 
                                <a href="#" class="ing">
                                    Testing Question 2 Title
                                </a>
                              </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <h5><span class="label label-primary">Answer</span></h5>
                                Testing Question 2 Content
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```